# RAM upgrade for PowerEdge T110 II

Tags: memory

I have a Dell PowerEdge T110 II which comes out of the box with 4 GB of RAM and it allows upgrading up to 32 GB. When I upgraded desktop with new RAM I got system failure light and machine won't boot up. Any idea what I am missing here as everything looks correct as per the spec?

**4 GB RAM which came with Dell PowerEdge T110**
[image: 4 GB RAM which came with Dell PowerEdge T110 II]

**Following is the RAM which I installed and it didn't work** Amazon [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006YG9C6C)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell PowerEdge T110 II supports DDR3 Unbuffered ECC Memory only. Maximum 32 GB using 4 x 8 GB

The 4 GB RAM in the pic is for 4 GB DDR3L 1600 MHz Unbuffered ECC, so it works.
The Amazon link memory is for 2 x 8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz Non-ECC. It will not work with your Dell PowerEdge T110 II.

For compatible memory specification, refer this link: http://www.memorystock.com/memory/DellPowerEdgeT110II.html